# Return value from SQL as button name, display text after clicking the button

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am doing a project that uses php and MySQL. I am really new to php and I have searched a lot but still haven't found a clean solution.

The problem is, firstly user inputs key words and it returns searched values(table names) to variables.

```
echo '<h2> Search Result: </h2>';
$searchSQL = "select distinct table_name from information_schema.columns where lower(column_name) like lower('%$search%') and table_schema='university'";
$result = $conn->query($searchSQL);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $table_name = $row['table_name'];
   echo "<input type='submit' name=$table_name value=$table_name>"."<br />";
 }
```

Now the buttons are created. If user clicks on any button,it should go further and return the column names of each table. I don't know how to do with non-static buttons.

Comment: just use a `form` tag, and just treat it just like any normal form, get the value of the submitted button, then just use `DESCRIBE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't forget to setup the actual `<form>`. Wrap them all up.

Second, I'd suggest, just use the same name attribute in your submit buttons:

```
name="table_name"
```

So it should look like this now:

```
echo '<h2> Search Result: </h2>';
$searchSQL = "
SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE LOWER(column_name) LIKE LOWER('%$search%') AND table_schema = 'university'
";

$result = $conn->query($searchSQL);

echo '<form method="POST" action="show_colums.php">'; // opening form tag

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $table_name = $row['table_name'];
    echo "<input type='submit' name='table_name' value='$table_name' /> <br/>";
                              //     ^ don use the $table_name in the name attribute
}

echo '</form>'; // closing form tag
```

Don't forget to also add the `action=""` attribute in the form tag. Just point it to whichever PHP script that will do the form processing. For this example, just use `show_columns.php`

Now, just apply the `DESCRIBE` in that PHP file that will process the selected button:

Inside `show_columns.php`:

```
if(!empty($_POST['table_name'])) {
    $table_name = $_POST['table_name']; // get input
    $sql = "DESCRIBE {$table_name}"; // use DESCRIBE
    $query = $conn->query($sql); // execute query
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) { // fetch rows
        // do whatver you need to do, table or whatever you like
        echo $row['Field']; // field name
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Or you can be a lot safer using prepared statements on the first form:

```
echo '<h2> Search Result: </h2>';
$searchSQL = "
    SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE LOWER(column_name) LIKE LOWER(?) AND table_schema = 'university'
    ";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($searchSQL);
$search = '%' . $search . '%';
$stmt->bind_param('s', $search);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($table_name);
echo '<form method="POST" action="show_columns.php">';
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<input type='submit' name='table_name' value='$table_name' /><br/>";
}
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: your script will create multiple submit button with same name, then how you distinguish it?

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu thats why i suggested using the same `name=""` attribute, that way, you could just use `$_POST['table_name']` in order to get the selected value, just one value is needed anyway

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating submit button create button `type='button'` Either using javascript/jquery or using html properties call a page which will return the table details:

```
echo "<input type='button' name='" . $table_name . "' value='" . $table_name .
     "' onclick=\"location.href='http://yourwebsite.com?tbl=" . $table_name."'\"><br />";
```

You can do the same calling some js function also.